# Moto 360 resolution and density

Tags: android

I'd like to know what is the exact resolution and density of not yet launched Moto 360 smartwatch.

I did some research and some sites say it is 320 x 320 but it looks much higher in the promotional videos.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! It would be most helpful if you could edit your question to expand on exactly what you mean. As it is now, it is not really a question_ . This saves everybody time, and makes it more likely that you will get helpful answers.

Comment: Let me check my encyclopaedia of unreleased smartwatches... :)

Comment: @MrE.Upvoter Feel free to google unreleased smart watches, there is a encyclopaedia (sort of). Lol.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a specification for an unreleased product. That's appropriate for a tech rumors site. It's not graphic design.

Answer (score 2):

[TechRadar](http://www.techradar.com/news/portable-devices/moto-360-vs-lg-g-watch-vs-the-samsung-gear-live-1254955) have posed information comparing smart watches.

The following is a snip of their article.

> If you want a circular smartwatch face, the Moto 360 is your only choice for the time being, though we don't know the exact measurements or resolution right now.

This was posted last month. Unfortunately, Motorola is being secretive about the Moto 360 specs for now.